# Windows 10 File Sorting

Tags: windows-10

I would be really grateful for anyone who could give me an answer here but essentially the premise of my task is that I have a large group of files with the same prefix name and then the date in the form DAYMONTHYEAR 01012000. On my computer which is running windows 10 they are sorted by integer value which basically means that they are sorted wrong because instead of being sorted year, month, day so that they are in order. The integer value just reads them left to right. My question is; does anyone know if there is any way that you can customise the arrangement of a large number of files e.g. 6th character value, then 4th character value, possibly by an algorithm etc. NOTE: there are over 1000 files so  I cannot change individual names.
Many Thanks, Jack

Comment: Probably need to script something to rename the files if they are consistant.  I ALWAYS write my dates YYYYMMDD due to this.

Comment: I don't think there is a way to sort by character position in Windows.  Is renaming the files completely out of the question, or just something you think would be too hard based on the number of files?  There are ways to batch process a rename that could be very quick.

Comment: Can you use a `dir` listing where they are sorted by creation or modification date? Does either of these correspond with the date embedded in the name?

Comment: Are you referring to the sort order in Explorer or in a `cmd` shell? There are differences ...

Comment: If you don't fancy scripting, there are free utilities that can help (e.g. https://www.advancedrenamer.com/), but renaming is going to be your only option in Windows Explorer.

Comment: Thanks to all of the people who answered, I really appreciate the help and will look into some of these things.